# how can I make a ng-bootstrap carousel responsive with a min height of 300px?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm currently trying to get a full width carousel in Angular with bootstrap with a minimal height of 300px. I'd like the picture to always be centered and when the minimal height has been reached, I'd like the sides to crop, so the image stays centered but it is nicely responsive.

Currently I have the following:

```
 <div class="container-fluid carouselcontainer">
  <div class="row">
    <ngb-carousel *ngIf="afbeeldingen">
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img [src]="afbeeldingen[0]" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Primi Piatti</h3>
          <p class="d-none d-md-block">Lekkere voorgerechten.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img [src]="afbeeldingen[1]" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Pizza's</h3>
          <p class="d-none d-md-block">Lekkere pizza's.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img [src]="afbeeldingen[2]" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Dolci</h3>
          <p class="d-none d-md-block">Lekkere deserten.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how I can get this right, could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Add min-height: 300px; height: //as per your need; to the .carouselcontainer class

Comment: @MontyGoldy But that doesn't crop the image and center it, the width just gets stretched smaller